# "incorrect number of arguments to numeric-type constructor at line" error in shader, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

Found a softbody asset for Unity on github that came with a shader. Due to a limited knowledge of shaders in Unity, I have no idea what the aforementioned error means.

Code (Line 22 is where the error is happening. I've marked it.):

```
Shader "Custom/Circle" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0

            float4 _Color;

            float4 frag(v2f_img i): COLOR {

                fixed4 transparent = float4(float3(_Color),0); // << ERROR IS HERE >>
                float distance = length(i.uv - float2(0.5, 0.5));
                float delta = fwidth(distance);
                float alpha = smoothstep(0.5, 0.5 - delta, distance);
                return lerp(transparent, _Color, alpha);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things wrong in your code:

**1**.You are passing one parameter to `float3` with `float3(_Color)`.

**2**.You are passing two parameters to `float4` with `float4(float3(_Color),0)`.

`float3` takes 3 parameters while `float4` and `fixed4` take 4 parameters. I think that the names says it it.

You have to pass each individual color component (`_Color.r`, `_Color.g`, `_Color.b`) to the `float3` then create `float4` with that.

That line of code should be:

```
fixed4 transparent = float4(float3(_Color.r, _Color.g, _Color.b),0);
```

Notice that `_Color.a`(alpha) is missing. That's what makes it transparent because the alpha is set to `0`.

---

I really don't think that `float3` is required here so this should really work too:

```
fixed4 transparent = float4(_Color.r, _Color.g, _Color.b, 0);
```

If you need it to be opaque then provide the alpha component too or replace the `0` with `1`.

```
fixed4 transparent = float4(_Color.r, _Color.g, _Color.b, _Color.a);
```

*Disclaimer*:

I am not a shader programmer but that should solve your problem.

Comment: Having poked at shaders on a few occasions, I gave this a whirl and you're correct on all counts.

Answer (score 3):

_Color has 4 channels in it but it is in float3 which gives you the error. So
try:

```
fixed4 transparent = float4(float3(_Color.rgb), 0);
```

or better yet:

```
fixed4 transparent = float4(_Color.rgb, 0);
```

as you don't have to cast a float3 as a float3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with ***float3(_Color)***, because the reference says that it takes 2 arguments, while you give just one ***_Color***

I don't have very much to do with shaders, so consider this as something that can help fix this, but doesn't have to:

***float3 variable = float3(_Color, 0);***

***float4(variable, 0);***

Try also add additional 0 after comma in float3 or float4 constructor, it might be 3 dimensional so it requires x, y and z

Comment: Well, as I said I'm not a specialist, but maybe try to make an seperate variable for float3, wait a second I'll edit answer

Comment: `_Color` is a float4, which you can't just pass to a float3 constructor, it doesn't know *which of those four you want to keep* (and adding a `,0` doesn't change that).  You **can** pass a float3 to a float4 because it can match the float3's rbg / xyz to the same fields in the float4, using the `,0` as the 4th value (a / w).